# Unclear on divergence of f*F

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y,z) = xyz^2$ and $F(x,y,z) = (xy, yz,zy)$. Compute divergince and curl of $G = (fF)$

Isn't that for $div(fF) = fdiv(F) + F\cdot \nabla f$?

Or do I just multiply $f$ by $F$ to find $G$ and then compute the divergence.

Comment: Both are all right.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\div{\mathop{\rm div}}\def\grad{\mathop{\rm grad}}$You can go both ways. You can use the formula 
$$ \div(fF) = f \div F + \langle \grad f, F\rangle $$
to compute $\div( fF)$, or you can first compute $fF$ and than take the divergence. This gives the same:
$$ (fF)(x,y,z) = (x^2y^2z^2, xy^2z^3, xy^2z^3) $$
and hence
\begin{align*}
  \div(fF)(x,y,z) &= 2xy^2z^2 + 2xyz^3 + 3xy^2z^2\\
      &= 5xy^2z^2 + 2xyz^3
\end{align*}
On the other hand 
\begin{align*}
  \grad f(x,y,z) &= (yz^2, xz^2, 2xyz)\\
  \div F(x,y,z) &= y+z+y\\
                &= 2y + z\\
(f\div F + \langle\grad f, F\rangle)(x,y,z) &= xyz^2(2y + z) + xy^2z^2 + xyz^3 + 2xy^2z^2\\
     &= 5xy^2z^2 + 2xyz^3.
\end{align*}